# missing function: _ZN4CoreC1Ev when running a emscripten js compiled file

Tags: c++, sdl, emscripten

So here is my Makefile file:

```
webgl:
    emcc -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -s SDL2_IMAGE_FORMATS='["bmp","png", "jpeg", "jpg"]' -s USE_SDL_TTF=2 -c main.cpp -o build/index.o
    emcc -O1 build/index.o -s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 -o build/index.js
```

Yes, I have been using SDL2 for my emscripten project and compiling it has the big error so I have added a `-s LLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0` to compile immediately without errors. After my attempt to build, it works but I can't run because of an error when I typed `node index.js` and pressing the Enter key.

```
missing function: _ZN4CoreC1Ev
Aborted(-1)
```

I searched up `_ZN4CoreC1Ev` on Google for solution but `Your search - _ZN4CoreC1Ev - did not match any documents.` it just said. Any solutions?

Comment: `_ZN4CoreC1Ev`  is the Core constructor `Core::Core()`.

Comment: @273K how did you decode it?

Comment: @TomRoggero Look for online name demanglers.